# How to get childs whose arrays contain a certain value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database scheme that is essentially the same that the one is the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#fanout) :

```
// An index to track Ada's memberships
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      // Index Ada's groups in her profile
      "groups": {
         // the value here doesn't matter, just that the key exists
         "techpioneers": true,
         "womentechmakers": true
      }
    },
    ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true,
        "eclarke": true
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

I would like to create a `DatabaseQuery` that gets **all users that take part of a specific group** (for instance users whose "groups" contain "techpionneers")

How should I proceed ? I tried a `Database.database().reference(withPath: "users").queryOrdered(byChild: "groups").queryEqual(toValue: "techpioneers")` but that does not work (obviously).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Franks solution is spot on but an alternative is to use a [Deep Query](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html) i.e. ordering by deep paths to query the users node for child->child nodes that match the criteria. Here's the format

```
    let ref = self.ref.child("users")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "groups/techpioneers").queryEqual(toValue: true)
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in 
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            print(snap)
        }
    })
```

the result is all of the users that are part of the techpioneers group

```
"alovelace": {
   "name": "Ada Lovelace",
   "groups": {
      "techpioneers": true,
      "womentechmakers": true
      }
}
```

Comment: That's a great answer, that way I don't have to make two queries. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To load all users that are part of a specific group, **start** in the `/groups` node to find their key:

```
ref.child("groups/techpioneers/members").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

That gives you the keys of all members. Then loop over those keys and load the corresponding user.

This is essentially a client-side join operations. While you may initially think this is incredibly slow, it's actually not all that bad since Firebase pipelines the requests over a single connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786.